# Publishing Azure App Service via Visual Studio fails

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-ad-b2c, azure-web-app-service

I am publishing my Azure App Service (.Net Backend) following [Publish the server project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk#publish-server-project)

That used to work but now I can't get it to work anymore. When I click publish in Visual Studio it builds and says

```
"========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped =========="
```

But in the web browser tab that is opening after that (normally the "This mobile app is up and running" screen appears) it sends me to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{domain}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=...` and right after that redirects me to `msala{custom-redirect-uri}://auth` which is the redirect URI for Azure AD B2C in my native app.

Also in activity log of my App Service in Azure Portal I don't see the update. When I query the database, the structure is not altered as it should be.

So what is happening there and why the redirect to the custom redirect URI? What has Azure AD B2C to do with publishing the backend project?

UPDATE:

Inspecting the opened web page, I see the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd' >  
<html xmlns = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' >  
<head>  
<title> Logging in... </title> 
<meta name = 'CACHE-CONTROL' content = 'NO-CACHE' />  
<meta name = 'PRAGMA' content = 'NO-CACHE' /> 
<meta name = 'EXPIRES' content = '-1' />
</head> 
<body > 
<form id = 'auto' method = 'post' action = 'msal{Client_id}://auth'>  
<div> 
<input type = 'hidden' name = 'error' id = 'error' value = 'redirect_uri_mismatch' /> 
<input type = 'hidden' name = 'error_description' id = 'error_description' value = 'AADB2C90006: The redirect URI &#39;https://{domain}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback&#39; provided in the request is not registered for the client id &#39;{Client_id}&#39;.
Correlation ID: 9569081c-2779-41e8-8b20-095384de402f
Timestamp: 2018-02-06 18:53:38Z
'/> 
<input type = 'hidden' name = 'state' id = 'state' value = 'redir=%2F' />  
</div>  
<div id = 'noJavascript' style = 'visibility: visible; font-family: Verdana' > 
<p> Although we have detected that you have Javascript disabled, you will be able to use the site as normal. </p> 
<p> As part of the authentication process this page may be displayed several times.Please use the continue button below. </p> 
<input type = 'submit' value = 'Continue' /> 
</div> 
<script type = 'text/javascript' >
   < !--
   document.getElementById('noJavascript').innerHTML = '';
   document.getElementById('auto').submit();
   //-->
</script></form></body></html>
```

I still do not see the connection from my native app client (client id) to my .Net Backend App Service. Sure they are connected, but hat should'nt have any impact on publishing he backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 'error_description' id = 'error_description' value = 'AADB2C90006: **The redirect URI 'https://{domain}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback**' provided in the request is not registered for the client id '{Client_id}'

If I understand you correctly, you are talking about the Xamarin app. In general, we would register a mobile / native application within the Azure Active Directory B2C tenant, and set the Custom Redirect URI / Redirect URIs. Details, you could follow [Register your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration#choose-next-steps-based-on-your-application-type).

Then we would use MSAL in the mobile client for retrieving the token, and use the [Client-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#clientflow) to send the token for authenticating with the mobile app backend as follows:

```
var payload = new JObject();
if (authenticationResult != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authenticationResult.IdToken))
{
   payload["access_token"] = authenticationResult.IdToken;
}
var user = await TodoItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory,payload);
```

Based on your description, I assumed that you have set **Action to take when request is not authenticated** to `Log in with Azure Active Directory` under the "SETTINGS > Authentication / Authorization" section of your mobile app. By default, if you access your mobile via browser, it would use the [Server-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#serverflow), at this point you need to set `https://{your-mobileapp-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback` under the Redirect URIs of your AAD app.

Moreover, here are some useful tutorials, you could refer to them:

[TodoAzureAuthADB2CClientFlow](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/d5c695a7eb830a6d52c042539f9c141244638738/WebServices/TodoAzureAuthADB2CClientFlow)

[Authenticating Users with Azure Active Directory B2C](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/authentication/azure-ad-b2c/)

[TodoAzureAuthADB2CServerFlow](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/d5c695a7eb830a6d52c042539f9c141244638738/WebServices/TodoAzureAuthADB2CServerFlow)

**Note:** For the server flow sample, you do not need to use MSAL, and you just need to directly login again your mobile app with the specific provider as follows:

```
var user = await TodoItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, Constants.URLScheme);
```

And you need to [Add your app to the Allowed External Redirect URLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users#redirecturl) for your mobile client app on Azure Portal.

**UPDATE:**

> But nevertheless, the changes I made were not reflected in he Azure DB. But this seems to be a problem with EF Migration on application start, which has to be configured first

For EF migration, if you disable the automatic migration, by default your database Initializer would be `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`, when the first time your app accessing the database, it would create the database if not exists. Or you could enable automatic migration and invoke `new DbMigrator(new Migrations.Configuration()).Update()` under the `ConfigureMobileApp` method of your Startup.MobileApp.cs file, at this time the changes would be applied on application start.

Since you are using ClientFlow and do not configure `https://{your-mobileapp-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback` under the Redirect URIs of your AAD app. Before publishing your application to Azure side via the VS, you could set the `LaunchSiteAfterPublish` to `False` under your `<your-mobile-app-name> - Web Deploy.pubxml` file as you commented to disable launching your website automatically after the publishment has been successfully completed.

Comment: I use ClientFlow and this works quite well. The errors come when publishing the Backend (App Service / Mobile App) to Azure. But I think I got the problem. After the app is published the App is opened in a browser window. And since it is not configured to work in a browser also he redirect does not work. I now jus disabled to open the app in the browser after publishing. I used to think the opening browser window has any impact in the publishing action, but it has not.

Comment: But nevertheless, the changes I made were not reflected in he Azure DB. But this seems to be a problem with EF Migration on application start, which has to be configured first. I did not read anything about that in any introductory example for Xamarin Backends and even the sample app is not configured for automatic migration. So I have to work that out first.

Comment: For EF migration, if you disable the automatic migration, by default your database Initializer would be `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`, when the first time your app accessing the database, it would create the database if not exists. Or you could enable automatic migration and invoke `new DbMigrator(new Migrations.Configuration()).Update()` under the `ConfigureMobileApp` method of your `Startup.MobileApp.cs` file.

Comment: Or you could just manually execute the database migration before publishing your mobile app backend to azure mobile side. Details you could follow adrian hall's book https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/server/

Comment: I will have a look at both of your methods, thank you. I already experimented with automatic migration but did not succeed.

Comment: Your link was great @BruceChen The only thing hat costed me hours was that I first had to query the API or table controller before the changes were visible in the Azure Portal Daabe query editor and also the activity log for the database in Azure Portal does no reflect the migration. If you can post this as an answer (together with the hint, that the opening browser tab after publishing is of no importance and can be disabled in Web Deploy.pubxml in tag LaunchSiteAfterPublish) I can accept it.

Comment: I updated my answer and summarized some details from our comments.